# How to make a list from different rows in a column if cell contains other information

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I have two sheets, one with computer information and another with processors. I want to add a column in the processor sheet that lists the computers that use those processor even if I change the order of any of the sheet.

[This is my Google Sheet exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAy9I.png)

I have found that this formula works only if the same row contains the data, not the whole column, since it gives off #VALUE errors for every E that is not contained in the same C row.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(SEARCH(E2:E;C2:C); JOIN(", ";B2:B); ""))
```

It also adds ALL the computers and not only the ones that have the same processors. In the screenshot it is CONCATENER but I found JOIN worked better.

Any suggestion or idea would be great. I have already had to change how the processors are written in both sheets so they would be easier to search by the formula. The point is to know what server I can use which processor without having to go between the two sheets all the time.

**EDIT**: Using this formula gives me what I want only in one cell but only adds one string of text even if there should be more.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(""; SI(E2=$C$2:$C; $B$2:$B & ","; "")))
```

[New Exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7oyX.png)

Comment: Something like `=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN("", if(E2=C2:C6, B2:B6, "")))` I think is a little closer to what you are looking for. You just end up with a trailing delimiter.

Comment: Thanks! It is closer but only for one cell and it does not make a string. Trying to copy/paste to other cells and I still have to change each formula one by one so it goes to the right cells. Edited question with added info.

Comment: You can just anchor so you can copy and paste like: `=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN("", if(E2=$C$2:$C$6, $B$2:$B$6 & ",", "")))` but I agree it could use a little more tweaking to scrub the commas (this version here in the comment comma delimits nicely, but leaves a trailing comma.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that's what the $ meant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you want. Put this in E2:

```
=unique(transpose(split(join(",";C:C)&join(",";C:C);",")))
```

Tis will create a list of unique processors in column E. Then put this in F2 and drag the formula down column F:

```
=if(E2<>"";join(", ";transpose(ifError(filter(B:B;ifError(search(E2;C:C);false)))));"")
```

This will join the list of computers in the cell in column F next to the processor.

Comment: Thank you!! This is way out of my league I would never have figured it out. The first formula is not necessary for my needs, but the second one is almost exactly what I need. Only "problem" is that I may want to sort the sheet that keeps the formula for whatever reason and that shambles all the data and nothing works anymore. *I'll just not do that*

Comment: These formulas continue to work fine if I sort the sheet. I tested by sorting on column B.

Comment: Yellow line is the sam: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LH5G.png & https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzmOE.png